# JButton and ActionListener producing several exceptions in java.awt, security, and event?

Tags: java, swing, events, jbutton, actionlistener

I have four buttons at east, west, north and south, and I'm trying to have the button that is pressed change it's text.  In Eclipse it seems problem-less before compiling, but when I do compile and try to press any of the four buttons, it displays many exceptions.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class gui {
    JButton rightbutton;
    JButton leftbutton;
    JButton downbutton;
    JButton upbutton;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        gui GUI = new gui();
        GUI.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("The Gui");
        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();

        JButton rightbutton = new JButton("Right Button");
        rightbutton.addActionListener(new rightListener());
        JButton leftbutton = new JButton ("Button of the west");
        leftbutton.addActionListener(new leftListener());
        JButton downbutton = new JButton ("Button on the bottom");
        downbutton.addActionListener(new downListener());
        JButton upbutton = new JButton ("Button in the sky");
        upbutton.addActionListener(new upListener());   

        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setSize(500,500);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);

        myFrame.getContentPane().add(myPanel);
        myFrame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST,rightbutton);
        myFrame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH,upbutton);
        myFrame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,downbutton);
        myFrame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST,leftbutton);
    }
        class rightListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                rightbutton.setText("Pushed");
            }
        }
        class leftListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                leftbutton.setText("Pushed");
            }
        }
        class downListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                downbutton.setText("Pushed");
            }
        }
        class upListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                upbutton.setText("Pushed");
            }
        }
}
```

Here are all of the exceptions that are given when I press any of the four buttons.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gui$leftListener.actionPerformed(gui.java:46)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gui$upListener.actionPerformed(gui.java:56)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please show your exceptions.

Comment: This is not a problem with the code you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are declaring the `JButtons`, but not putting them in the instance variables reserved for them. You can fix this by replacing lines like:

```
JButton rightbutton = new JButton("Right Button");
```

with:

```
rightbutton = new JButton("Right Button");
```

The first form declares local variables that overshadow the instance variables, so the instance variables disappear. The null pointer exceptions happen when a listener tries to access an instance variable, which is actually null because it has never been initialized.

Another way you can fix this problem is by using `event.getSource()` instead of using the instance variable, in which case the instance variables become superfluous.